# Local Network Connection, No internet

Tags: 16.04, networking

My server is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am able to connect to it on my local network but I am unable to communicate out to either internal or external ips. I'm pretty new to networking so I'm not sure what to do exactly.

Here's resolv.conf

```
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
search hsd1.mi.comcast.net
```

Here's network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Primary Network Interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Here's ifconfig:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:4f:27:0e:c2
          inet addr:10.0.0.144  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:404:cf00:131:21e:4fff:fe27:ec2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:4fff:fe27:ec2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3412971 errors:0 dropped:490 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2827256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:484956659 (484.9 MB)  TX bytes:419007083 (419.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:318095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:318095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:19096128 (19.0 MB)  TX bytes:19096128 (19.0 MB)
```

Here's route -env

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-6535b59b431b
```

**Update!**

It turns out that I am unable to communicate out from my server, be it internal or external ips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my firewall. I ran `ufw status verbose` and everything looked good, but I disabled it just to check and voila! I had internet access.

I ran `ufw reset` and then reconfigured my rules and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the server's network configuration and routing table, because as it stands, I can only see your DNS being set to `75.75.75.75` and `75.75.76.76`

Enter the following command from the command prompt and the output to your original question above.

```
ifconfig
route -env
```

Under normal condition, you need 3 things configured to be able to access external IPs

1. IP address.
2. Routing table (with default gateway configured).
3. DNS server.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. I've added the output from those commands.

Comment: Strange, both network configuration and routing seem good. With the DNS set to 75.75.75.75, things should be working already. The network configuration even shows that it is able to receive and tranmit data, i.e., 3412971 packets received and 2827256 packets transmited. Have you tried access via ip address? Try "ping www.google.com" and then "ping 216.58.193.68"